# Trying to Split the filename so that I can put it into 3 separate Strings

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am uploading files to a directory and I am also just getting the file itself not the directory and the folders.

For example I am getting only this `6122002_Abstract_9-11-07.pdf` by using this code `hpf.FileName.Substring(hpf.FileName.LastIndexOf("\") + 1)`.

What I want to do is separate out the 6122002, the Abstract, and the date which is 9-11-07 so I can insert it into a sql database.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have this `6122002_Abstract_9-11-07.pdf`
Try something like

```
Dim Arr() As String
str = "6122002_Abstract_9-11-07.pdf"
Arr = str.Split("_")
```

so the array will contain *6122002*, *Abstract* and *9-11-07.pdf*

**update**

```
Dim number As String = Arr(0)
Dim name AS String = Arr(1)
Dim date As String = Arr(2).Substring(0, Arr(2).Length-4)
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly but I have already tried that.  The issue I am having is trying to then extract the split so I can insert it into a sql database table.

Comment: you can use the array index to access the each element

Comment: Can you maybe provide an example?  I'm extremely stuck.

Comment: He is saying Please complete my Homework to get full marks(10 marks for Upvote and 15 marks for acceptance). So finally you will get 25/25 marks. :)

Comment: Awesome.  Thank you so much.  It's working finally.  Sometimes it's such a simple thing but you get stuck and I was stuck.  Thanks again humpty dumpty.

Answer (score 0):

To get the filename without the path and without the extension you can use

```
IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)
```

And you probably should want the date part as a DateTime. You could make a class which takes a filename in its constructor and parses out the parts into properties, for example

```
Module Module1

    Public Class Paper
        Public Property SerialNumber As UInt64
        Public Property Type As String
        Public Property PublishedDate As DateTime

        Public Sub New(filename As String)
            Dim parts() As String = IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filename).Split("_"c)
            ' You should check there are three parts here.
            ' Also, you could use TryParse to make sure the parsing works.
            Me.SerialNumber = UInt64.Parse(parts(0))
            Me.Type = parts(1)
            Dim dateformats() As String = {"dd-MM-yy"} ' could add more if required
            Me.PublishedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(parts(2),
                                                   dateformats,
                                                   New Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"),
                                                   Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)

        End Sub

    End Class

    Sub Main()
        Dim fs = IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\temp\threeparts")
        Dim papers As New List(Of Paper)

        For Each f In fs
            papers.Add(New Paper(f))
        Next

        For Each p In papers
            Console.WriteLine("Serial: {0}, Type: {1}, Published: {2}", p.SerialNumber, p.Type, p.PublishedDate.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"))
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```